# Django LiveServerTestCase: disable SSL at test-time

Tags: python, django, ssl

I have a CBV with a "require_ssl" decorator (from [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1351/)) which redirects the client to the same url path under HTTPS.

I'm attempting to disable SSL at test-time while LiveServerTestCase is running (since it defaults to non-secured ).

This needs to be based on server configuration at test-time, not a HTTP header injected by the client (since this could be injected in production). I just can't find any flag to signify that the Django test server is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this via the [@override_setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings) decorator (present since Django 1.4).

My 'require_ssl' decorator can now check for the presence of a test-time setting:

```
getattr(settings, 'UNDER_TEST', False)
```